# I can't boot into ubuntu after installation from CD!

Tags: 12.04, boot

Yesterday I created an Ubuntu installation CD. 
Installation process went well, I created some new partitions, waited through the whole installation process and within 30 minutes it was finished.
Then it asked me to remove my CD and press enter, which I did. Then it re-booted into Windows 7 (my main OS), but I wanted to boot into Ubuntu instead.
It didn't show any boot up screen or anything else for OS selection.

I've tried looking up some tutorials I even tried alt + f12 but that didn't help either.

My specs are:
1TB hard drive
8 GB RAM
intel 5
NVIDIA GTX 560

I wanted to dual boot for a while and I really want this problem fixed, I'm currently on the "Try Ubuntu"  and that works all well etc.

Thanks already,

Nick.

Answer (score 0):

with live CD put in terminal

```
$sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX

$sudo update-grub

$sudo reboot
```

Where sdaX means, your hard disk which is booting. If only physical disk is there it should be `sda`